# Horizontall bar with three states (like Lyft app)

Tags: android

I think a picture is more meaningful a long speech so here what I want to do

[image: Taken from lyft application]

I wonder how lyft has realised animation to switch from **Line** to **Lyft** or **Plus** (just bellow toolBar)

What did they use as widget ?

Is it a custom seekBar ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is basically https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar but with custom drawables for the slider and sliderbackground.

you could also modify a normal slider :) with custom label positions and other stuff.

The fancy thing will be to label the slider iself.

Comment: Ok thanks for the link. If you are another resources feel free to share on this thead :)